# how to separate string value of the another stuffs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, uialertview

```
 UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Logging in" message:@"you are a member in our website \nWelcome Dear  %@ ",UserName.text
            delegate:self
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

this code is showing error for me because I put in the string variable which is the text of a text field called "user name"

so how can I separate this line?

`initWithTitle:@"Logging in" message:@"you are a member in our website \nWelcome Dear  %@ ",UserName.text delegate:self`

because the error is showing here in the word delegate
HELP

Answer (score 1):

Use following format :

```
UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Logging in" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"you are a member in our website \nWelcome Dear  %@ ",UserName.text]
            delegate:self
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure it as follows:

```
NSString *psMsg = [NSString stringFromFormat: @"you are a member in our website \nWelcome Dear  %@ ", UserName.text, nil];
UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Logging in" message:psMsg
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
    otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Break things up so that it's easier to debug and understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
NSString *alertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"you are a member in our website \nWelcome Dear  %@",UserName.text];
UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Logging in" message:alertstr
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not creating a string as your parameter.

You can fix this by either declaring your string in line (Option 1) or by moving the string creation outside UIAlert view  (Option 2).

I like using localized strings (Option 3) for all strings as it helps with by getting strings out of code, allows for string reuse and aids with Internationalization.

Option 1:

```
UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Logging in" 
                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"you are a member in our website \nWelcome Dear  %@ ",UserName.text]
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Option 2:

```
NSString *alertstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"you are a member in our website \nWelcome Dear  %@",UserName.text];

UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Logging in" message:alertstr
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Option 3:

```
UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Login-title", nil) 
                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"Login-message",nil)
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done", nil)
                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this is the only way, and no need to show logging in when you are displaying that message.

```
UIAlertView *myAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"you are a member in our website Welcome Dear " message:mytext.text
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

[myAlert show];
[myAlert release];
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Check other answers.